# Spotbugs-filter classname-suffix

Tags: java, regex, xml, spotbugs

If you [create a filter XML-file](http://spotbugs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/filter.html#match-bugs-using-the-not-filter-operator) for spotbugs like this

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <FindBugsFilter xmlns="https://github.com/spotbugs/filter/3.0. ..."> 
   <Match><Class name="de.test.Test.ClassASuffix" /></Match>
  </FindBugsFilter>
```

it works perfectly for java-class `ClassASuffix`.
But it's tedious to add more rules like

```
 <Match><Class name="de.test.Test.ClassASuffix" /></Match>
 <Match><Class name="de.test.Test.ClassBSuffix" /></Match>
 <Match><Class name="de.test.Test.ClassCSuffix" /></Match>
```

How can you filter out all classes with *Suffix ?

I've already tried [some of these examples](http://spotbugs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/filter.html#match-bugs-using-the-not-filter-operator). (like `.*Test"`) But it just doesn't work.

Comment: Try `.*\.Test\..*` or `.*Suffix`

Comment: The second one does *not* work.  I did not test the first one, because there are Classes in test.Test that I want to examine.

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
<Match><Class name="~.*?Suffix.*" /></Match>
```